# Designing a view combination of TextView and ImageView

Tags: android, view

I want to develop a view which can works as both ImageView and TextView.Generally its possible by extending the both class but Java doesn't supports the Multiple Inheritance.

Then is it possible to do this ? and how ?

Comment: why you want? FYI, you can design custom view by extending View.

Comment: Why don't you simply set the background for your TextView  and set the text to it when required?

Comment: but i need the all features of ImageView and TextView in to single view

Answer (score 2):

I know I am posting this very late and you might have fixed the issue too! Still thought of sharing a work around.

I had a similar requirement and realized that GridView is not best suited for this. I implemented this by using a TableLayout and defining the elements of TableRows as ImageView or TextView. This can serve as a workaround to you if you have a static UI structure, meaning you know which table index should contain which element. Hope this helps someone.

```
<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/tableLayout3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:shrinkColumns="*"
    android:stretchColumns="*"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tagGrid">

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:layout_height="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_height="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:src="@drawable/orange"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_height="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:src="@drawable/blue"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_height="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:src="@drawable/yellow"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_height="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:src="@drawable/milkman"/>

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_height="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:src="@drawable/check"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv1"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:text="10.4"
                android:gravity="center" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv2"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:text="10.4"
                android:gravity="center" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv3"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:text="10.4"
                android:gravity="center" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv4"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:text="10.4"
                android:gravity="center" />

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_height="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:src="@drawable/cross"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv5"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:text="10.4"
            android:gravity="center" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv6"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:text="10.4"
            android:gravity="center" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv7"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:text="10.4"
            android:gravity="center" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv8"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:text="10.4"
            android:gravity="center" />

    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

TextView has parameter "DrawableTop/Left/Right".

Answer (score 0):

To do this you can create a custom `View` by extending the `View` class. [Here](http://kahdev.wordpress.com/2008/09/13/making-a-custom-android-button-using-a-custom-view/) is an example of creating a custom button `View`. It is not exactly what you are looking for since it is showing a custom `Button`, but i believe it will get you started.